# Using variable JSON names in match(regex)

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a webapp that will allow users to search a JSON file that contains several name-data pairs.  I'm using fetch to get the JSON data and then filter it (see code below).

The JSON data looks like this:

```
 {

    "Name": "Abelia grandiflora",

    "Cultivar": "cv. Edward Goucher",

    "Type": "Softwood, terminal or subterminal",

    "Stage": "n/a",

    "Taken": "July",

    "Medium": "Perlite or well drained medium",

    "Auxin": "Hormex - full strength",

    "Structure": "mist",

    "Heat": "No Bottom Heat .",

    "Percent": "100%",

    "Time": "4 weeks",

    "Care": "n/a",

    "Location": "Honolulu, Hawaii.",

    "Reference": "Oka, P. 1978. Propagation of Abelia grandiflora Edward Goucher. The Pl. Prop. 24(1):4-5."

  }
```

To retrieve the JSON data:

```
const getPlants = async () => {
     const res = await fetch('data/plants.json');
     plants = await res.json();
};
```

To filter data based on user text input:

```
const searchPlants = searchText => {

     let matches = plants.filter(plant => {

     const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');

     return plant.Name.match(regex);

});
```

"Name" in the "return plant.Name.match(regex);" expression is what I'd like to make variable.  I'd like it to be altered by user input.  For example, the JSON data has name-data pairs that include "Name" (as above) as well as "Cultivar" and "Reference".  If the user chooses to search based on "Cultivar" or "Reference", how do I replace "Name" in the return statement with "Cultivar" or "Reference"?

Comment: Do be aware using regex like this can cause lots of errors for your users.  Eg, type `[` into your search for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference an object with keys aswell. So in your case if you could adapt your `searchPlant` function to allow for a selector as such:

```
const searchPlants = (searchText, selector = 'Name') => {

     let matches = plants.filter(plant => {

     const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');

     return plant[selector].match(regex);

});
```

Comment: That did the trick!  I appreciate the help very much.  I'm getting the "selector" value from user input in the HTML that calls the script.